# How to stop full-text index population?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Oops! I managed to trigger population of all full-text indexes in all databases!

They now hog the CPU and all the threads for themself!

How do I stop them?

Comment: For the record, the "emergency" has passed, but next time, I would like to be able to do something more than just wait it over. Obviously, the best course of action would be to ensure there is no "next time", but let's be realistic.